# App Name not displaying on Action Bar

Tags: android, commonsware

In a few of the commonsware app samples, the app name text is not displaying on the action bar.
For example the Containers demo apps have just a grey coloured bar with no text.
Any idea why the text is not showing?

Comment: Those samples are ancient and still use the pre-Holo theme, which had an old-style grey title bar. Updating their manifests and moving them all to the Holo theme is on my to-do list for this summer. However, their titles should still appear in that bar -- I just ran the Linear Percent Demo on a 4.3 emulator with no issue.

Comment: I ran the app and the text shows up on the emulator. It just doesn't display in the main.xml graphical layout for some reason.

Comment: Oh, that's probably a limitation of the GUI editor preview.

Comment: Another sample "Linear percent demo" has quite different colours in the emulator compared to the graphical layout. Black Action Bar compared to Grey. Dark buttons compared to light grey buttons. Is it not uncommon for the GUI preview to be a bit different?